# Convert a value to the existing xScale

Tags: d3.js, nvd3.js

I need to write a line to the vnd3, how to convert it to the nvd3 coordinate system, if can convert my value to the axis, and return me the translate value, so I can draw a 'g' to use translate to draw the line.

for example,
 [image]

I want to add a blue line, just assume the value is 18, so how to write the line in the exising axis.The solution I think is : 
computing the xScale to convert the new value to the chart domain, then use 'g' to translate,

am I right ?

Comment: Could you please add some more information about what you are trying to do here? The question is difficult to understand for me.

Comment: @musically_ut Thanks for your advise, It is really hard to discribe, I'm added a screenshot, so could you understand now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create an `nvd3` model, you can call various functions on it to get the scales, axis, and other configurable parameters from it.

I could not find a place where this rather large API surface is documented. The source code, however, is easy to read and work around.

For example, the [`lineChart` model](https://github.com/novus/nvd3/blob/master/src/models/lineChart.js#L357-L361) has the following API:

```
  //============================================================
  // Expose Public Variables
  //------------------------------------------------------------

  // expose chart's sub-components
  chart.dispatch = dispatch;
  chart.lines = lines;
  chart.legend = legend;
  chart.xAxis = xAxis;
  chart.yAxis = yAxis;
  chart.interactiveLayer = interactiveLayer;

  d3.rebind(chart, lines, 'defined', 'isArea', 'x', 'y', 'size', 'xScale', 'yScale', 'xDomain', 'yDomain', 'xRange', 'yRange'
    , 'forceX', 'forceY', 'interactive', 'clipEdge', 'clipVoronoi', 'useVoronoi','id', 'interpolate');

  chart.options = nv.utils.optionsFunc.bind(chart);

  chart.margin = function(_) { ... }
  chart.width = function(_) { ... }
  chart.height = function(_) { ... }
  chart.color = function(_) { ... }

  chart.showLegend = function(_) { ... }
  chart.showXAxis = function(_) { ... }
  chart.showYAxis = function(_) { ... }
  chart.rightAlignYAxis = function(_) { ... }
  chart.useInteractiveGuideline = function(_) { ... }
  chart.tooltips = function(_) { ... }
  chart.tooltipContent = function(_) { ... }
  chart.state = function(_) { ... }
  chart.defaultState = function(_) { ... }
  chart.noData = function(_) { ... }

  chart.transitionDuration = function(_) { ... }
```

Most of these functions are self-explanatory.

You can get access to the `xScale` and the `margins` by calling the functions `model.xScale()` and `model.margin()` respectively. Then you can, as you suggested, create a `g` with a `line` inside and place it on the graph.